# How to replace part of header, remove between two characters bash, awk, sed

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a tab delimited file.

```
abc_a1.txt\tcde_b2.txt\tefgh_c11.txt\t....
1\t2\t3\t...
```

I would like to strip anything after `_` for each column header. I would like to get

```
abc\tcde\tefgh\t...
1\t2\t3\t...
```

How do I do that. Tried, `sed –i ‘s/_.*//g’` and it stripped all after first `_`
Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have literal text `\t` or `\t` are tabs?

Comment: @anubhava, they are tabs, not literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `gnu sed` you can use a negated bracket expression:

```
sed 's/_[^\t]*//g' file
```

`_[^\t]*` matches underscore followed by zero or more non-tab characters.

Answer (score 1):

try in awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/_[^\\]*/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

try in sed:

```
sed 's/_[^\\]*//g'   Input_file
```

EDIT: As OP said \t are the TABs in Input_file so adding following solution too now.

```
awk '{gsub(/_[^\t]*/,"");print}'  Input_file
```

Comment: I think I confused you with typing literal `\t`, but I now know how to process if it has literal `\t`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/_[^\t]*\t/\t/g'
```

if you're not worried about the last field.

```
sed 's/_[^\t]*\t/\t/g;s/_[^\t]*$//'
```

otherwise.

Comment: Thanks,`\t` were not literal but tab. I am sure your answer works too.